# Distinct Count of Items Having Distinct Count of Other Items

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

I have data that look like this:

[image: IMG:]

What I want is a distinct count of the number of dates which have a distinct count of Person equal to two.  The answer should here be one.

I am in Excel Power Pivot and I have tried:

```
=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT([Date]),Filter('Table',[Distinct Count of Person] = 2)
```

But this does not yield the results.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably do part of this with an Excel formula, but to do both parts in the Data Model, you can add a column that counts the distinct person values against each date:

The formula for the DistinctNamesPerDate **column**:

```
=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Person]), ALLEXCEPT(Table1, Table1[Date]))
```

Note that distinctcount of person is better than countrows, so you can handle the situation where the same person is on a date more than once.

Then create a measure that does a distinct count of dates where the DistinctNamesPerDate is greater than 1.

The formula for the DistinctDatesWithMultipleNames **measure**:

```
DistinctDatesWithMultipleNames:=CALCULATE(DISTINCTCOUNT(Table1[Date]),Table1[DistinctNamesPerDate]>1)
```

You can see that the pivot table returns 2, as expected:

[image]